# Tax change estimates in government documents [US]

Tags: united-states, taxes, legislation, data-sources

I am conducting research that involves gathering estimates of the effects of changes to the tax code in the US. In particular, I am interested in using contemporary, publicly available government documents. The goal is to create a similar measure to that of [Romer and Romer (2009)](https://eml.berkeley.edu/~dromer/papers/nadraft609.pdf). So far I've been able to identify several sources that are published on a regular basis (US Budget, Economic Report of the President, CBO's Budget Outlook), and several published on a per-bill basis (House and Senate Reports, Joint Committee on Taxation Report, various CBO documents). My questions are:

1. Are there any official regulations in the US requiring a certain body to prepare estimate of the effects of tax changes? - I have looked and looked and cannot find any.
2. Have I omitted any prominent sources?
3. EDIT: I would also appreciate some source listing the tax changes, at least since 2007 since I haven't been able to find one either.

*I hope my question fits this section. Or is there a more suitable section for this?*

Comment: Have you looked in the House and Senate rules?  That is where I would expect budget rules to be written.  In particular, that's where you would find rules requiring that the budget meet certain requirements under CBO scoring (e.g. no increase in the deficit past ten years).